# Attempting to integrate a WebRTC SDK into a React Native UI Module

Tags: android, webrtc, android-view, react-native

Okay, I'm going to provision this with the fact I know little android native code.  I am dropping down into the android native code from react-native in an attempt to use a peer to peer video conference sdk.

The SDK I am attempting to use is the Skylink SDK, and I'm trying to wrap it in react-native ui module.

I have got close to providing a view, and the SDK is triggering successfully, but I am currently hitting an error where the SDK is complaining:

```
ResourceType: No known package when getting name for resource number 0xffffffff
09-13 09:57:14.237 25504 25781 I org.webrtc.Logging: SurfaceViewRenderer: No surface to draw on
```

The app crashes as a result of this.

My code is below, but I suspect I am missing a large chunk of basic logic.

I am also having trouble confirming if react-native is even rendering the surface renderer into the app.

Skylink SDK - https://cdn.temasys.com.sg/skylink/skylinksdk/android/latest/doc/reference/packages.html

Skylink Example Android App - 
https://github.com/Temasys/skylink-android-sample

```
package com.reactlibrary;

import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.Callback;

//import com.facebook.Fresco;

import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.VideoView;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.app.Activity;

import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.listener.LifeCycleListener;
import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.listener.MediaListener;
import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.listener.RemotePeerListener;

import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.SkylinkConnection;
import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.SkylinkException;
import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.UserInfo;
import sg.com.temasys.skylink.sdk.rtc.SkylinkConfig;

import com.facebook.react.uimanager.SimpleViewManager;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.annotations.ReactProp;

import org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;


public class SkylinkViewManager extends SimpleViewManager<SurfaceViewRenderer> {

    public static final String REACT_CLASS = "RNSkylinkView";

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return REACT_CLASS;
    }

    private static SkylinkConnection skylinkConnection;

    private Activity mActivity = null;

    private ThemedReactContext mContext = null;

    private String roomName = null;
    private String userName = null;
    private String appKey = null;
    private String secret = null;

    private SurfaceViewRenderer appointmentView = null;

    private SkylinkConfig getSkylinkConfig() {
        SkylinkConfig config = new SkylinkConfig();

        config.setAudioVideoSendConfig(SkylinkConfig.AudioVideoConfig.AUDIO_AND_VIDEO);
        config.setTimeout(60);

        return config;
    }

    public void initAppointment(ThemedReactContext context) {

        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "INITIALISED APPOINTMENT");

        skylinkConnection = SkylinkConnection.getInstance();
        skylinkConnection.init(
                "API_KEY_HERE",
                getSkylinkConfig(),
                context
        );

        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "INITIALISED APPOINTMENT");
    }

    public void startAppointment() {

        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Attempting Appointment start");
        if(roomName != null && userName != null && appKey != null && secret != null){

            Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "STARTING APPOINTMENT " + roomName + " " + userName + " " + appKey + " " + secret);
            boolean connection_success;
            connection_success = skylinkConnection.connectToRoom(secret, roomName, userName);

            Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "APPOINTMENT CONNECTED " + connection_success);

            if (connection_success == true) {
                changeToView();
            }

        } else {

            Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Variables arent ready, aborted appointment start");

        }


    }

//    private boolean setListeners(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
//        if (skylinkConnection != null) {
//            skylinkConnection.setLifeCycleListener(reactContext.);
//            skylinkConnection.setMediaListener(this);
//            skylinkConnection.setOsListener(this);
//            skylinkConnection.setRemotePeerListener(this);
//            return true;
//        } else {
//            return false;
//        }
//    }

    public void changeToView() {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Attempting to Switch views");
        appointmentView = skylinkConnection.getVideoView(null);

    }


    @ReactMethod
    public void getConnectionInfo(Callback callback) {

//      UserInfo user_data = skylinkConnection.getUserInfo(null);
        String room_id = skylinkConnection.getRoomId();

        callback.invoke(room_id);
    }

    @Override
    public SurfaceViewRenderer createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {

        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Creating View Instance");
        mContext = context;

        appointmentView = new SurfaceViewRenderer(context);
        appointmentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        appointmentView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        appointmentView.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
        appointmentView.getLayoutParams().width = 100;
        appointmentView.setBackgroundColor(0x00FF00);  // Just making this appear
        appointmentView.bringToFront();

        initAppointment(context);

        return appointmentView;
    }

    public void updateView () {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Updating the view");
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "roomName")
    public void setRoomName(SurfaceViewRenderer view, @Nullable String room_name) {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Setting Room Name "+room_name);
        roomName = room_name;
        startAppointment();
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "userName")
    public void setUserName(SurfaceViewRenderer view, @Nullable String user_name) {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Setting User Name "+user_name);
        userName = user_name;
        startAppointment();
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "appKey")
    public void setAppKey(SurfaceViewRenderer view, @Nullable String app_key) {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Setting App Key "+app_key);
        appKey = app_key;
        startAppointment();
    }

    @ReactProp(name = "secret")
    public void setSecret(SurfaceViewRenderer view, @Nullable String this_secret) {
        Log.d("APPOINTMENT", "Setting secret "+this_secret);
        secret = this_secret;
        startAppointment();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for ANY pointers or help.

Comment: Hi there!

I might be facing the same problem of using skylink sdk from a react native application. Did you manage to end up with something working?